# How to import and export js files using es6 modules

Tags: javascript

I'm having troubles using the es6 modules feature at the most basic level.

Looking at MDN documentation I saw many variations of using that feature, but none of them worked for me. Consider the following snippet:

```
//importer.js
"use strict";

import * as imported from "./exporter";

imported.foo();
```

```
//exporter.js
"use strict";

export const foo = () => console.log('success');
```

```html
//main.html
<html>
<head>
<script src = "./importer.js"></script>
</head>
</html>
```

I expect the following code to log 'success' so I know that 'imported module' managed to import the foo function from 'exported module'.

I've tried some other variations as well like export with parenthesis {} or default export just as written in MDN.

Obviously i'm missing something basic. 
Your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You forgot `type="module"`

Comment: @andymccullough Pretty much any modern browser created in the past few years does support ES6. (ES6 was ES2015, after all)

Comment: `function () => console.log('success');` is invalid syntax.

Comment: Edited. thanks. still same problem...

Answer (score 1):

In your html script element please add `type="module"` attribute and in your importer file you need to add the file extension

```
 import * as imported from "./exporter.js";
```

Comment: Done. now I get blocked by CORS policy: Access to script at [...]' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Comment: did you add both file in in script tag or not ??

Comment: you need to add the `exporter.js` file in the script tag also.

Comment: @TamirNakar Please run your script in your local server or any domain, is not work as an HTML file. and also you don't need to add `<script>` tag for exporter.js file.

Comment: @kousheralampranto, added it also for `exporter.js`. same result.

Comment: @SanatGupta are you saying that this feature wasn't designed to work the way I did it on a plain HTML file? because that's exactly the way I want it.

Comment: oh man, please use a server to run your script. this feature will not work by opening the html file in browser.

Comment: @TamirNakar Yes need a server for access this feature please check above restriction for that.

Answer (score 0):

CORS is layered over HTTP so it makes somehow no sense to deal with CORS besides http https chrome and chrome-extension since the last 3 probably (I lack doc here) relies over the same rules as HTTP.

Any other protocol behavior for CORS is undefined for now. So Chrome blocks it.

To answer each question individually:

1) No, they just consider that since the CORS is not defined for other protocol, the safest is to crash with an error saying "not implemented"

2) Since 1) answer is No, this question is not applicable. But if Chrome let the request go, then it's up to the unknown-protocol to properly handle CORS, which will probably not be done right

3) The difference between Firefox and Chrome is that Firefox first check if origins of the requester document and the requested resource are the same (and if so, it let it through, otherwise, it follow CORS process) while Chrome always follow the CORS process before checking the origin matching.

-I don't know which behavior follow best the Fetch specification- It seems that both are ok since part of the spec says

"file" "ftp"

For now, unfortunate as it is, file and ftp URLs are left as an exercise for the reader.

When in doubt, return a network error.

The only harm I could see is that Firefox would let a script display sensitive information from file:/// on your screen, that a shoulder spyer could grab. It's not related to CORS then.

Comment: @TamirNakar this future need to the server is not work as HTML file.